# Jest + SuperTest tests passes locally but not exiting and keep running on GitHub actions

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jestjs, github-actions, supertest

I'm trying to test API routes using jest & supertest as well as creating github action workflow for Continue Integration. I'm new and trying to learn both testing and CI/CD in NodeJs/Express.
I've no clue if I'm doing something wrong with tests or CI/CD. My best guess is if there's open handles in my tests But there is no warning for open handles locally.

**node.yml** file:

```
name: E-Commerce Project CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
jobs:
  build:
    env:
      CI: true
      MONGO_URL: mongodb://localhost/ECOM
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x, 18.x]
        mongodb-version: ["4.2", "4.4", "5.0"]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Git checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Start MongoDB
        uses: supercharge/mongodb-github-action@1.7.0
        with:
          mongodb-version: ${{ matrix.mongodb-version }}

      - run: npm install
      - run: npm test
```

**Test File** :

```
const request = require('supertest');
const path = require('path');
const app = require('../app');
const {
    mongoConnect,
    mongoDisconnect,
} = require('../services/mongo');

describe('E commerce API', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await mongoConnect();
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await mongoDisconnect();
    });

    const randString = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);

    describe('Test POST register user', () => {
        test('It should respond with 201 created and success is true', async () => {

            const response = await request(app)
                .post('/api/user/register')
                .field('name', 'test name')
                .field('email', `${randString}@gmail.com`)
                .field('password', '1234')
                .field('type', '1')
                .field('mobile', '12345')
                .expect(201)

            expect(response.body.success).toBe(true);
        });
    });

    describe('Test POST add category', () => {
        var token = null;

        beforeAll(function (done) {
            request(app)
                .post('/api/user/login')
                .send({
                    email: `${randString}@gmail.com`,
                    password: '1234',
                })
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    token = res.body.accessToken;
                    done();
                });
        });
        test('It should respond with 201 and success is true', function (done) {
           request(app)
                .post('/api/category/add')
                .send({category: randString})
                .set('Authorization', token)
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    done();
                    expect(res.status).toBe(201);
                    expect(res.body.success).toBe(true);
                });
        });
    });

});
```

**GitHub Actions Picture** :
[image]

As you can notice **Run npm test** is running for 20 mins+, and it won't exit even for hours. And it is passing locally without any *open handles* as I have tagged **--detectOpenHandles** in jest test script.

*it is a pain for me, I've no clue, Please help me...*

Comment: What is the nodejs version you use locally?

Comment: 16.16.0 node version on my local machine

Comment: Try running `ci/cd` using `node-version` of `16.x` only and see how it behaves. According to your screenshot it fails with `node-version` `14.x` so I would start making sure the issue is not related to the node version.

Comment: I've tried using 16.x and it still not exiting, I've also tried being specific to mongo version 5.0 but that did not work as well

Answer (score 0):

After 7 hours struggle, I came to know that my .env file was unavailable, which cause to miss variables like secret_key, Mongo_URL etc. So, I provided .env variables to my repository and it worked for me.

Here is the code I added in node.yml file:

```
- name: Create .env file
        uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.3
        with:
          envkey_DEBUG: false
          envkey_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET }}
          envkey_REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET: ${{ secrets.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET }}
          envkey_EMAIL_USER: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_USER }}
          envkey_EMAIL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD }}
          envkey_MONGO_URL: ${{ secrets.MONGO_URL }}
          file_name: .env
          fail_on_empty: true
```

note: you also must provide your .env variables in your repository as repository secret.